# Zendframework / PgSQL fetchAll orderby

Tags: php, zend-framework, sql-order-by, postgresql, fetchall

i have a pgsql table with fields id, identifier, name.

```
  id serial NOT NULL,
  identifier character varying(16),
  name character varying(128)
```

I want to `fetchAll` values from the table orderby identifier.

but identifier is having values

```
12, 100, 200, 50
```

and after `$table->fetchAll(null, 'identifier');`
is giving the result

```
100, 12, 200, 50
```

but I want the result as

```
12, 50, 100, 200
```

or using a direct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this query will work for you

```
select * from tablename order by tableField::int
```

Comment: also $table->fetchAll(null, '(identifier::int)'); will work with zend

tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$table->fetchAll(null, '(identifier+0)');
```

The `+0` operation should make PostgreSQL cast the identifier value to an integer, so it sorts numerically instead of alphabetically.

The presence of parentheses should give Zend Framework a clue to treat the sorting argument as an expression, not a column name.